# unknown column xxx in where clause using joins, group by and fulltext

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, mysql-error-1054

What is wrong with my query?

```
SELECT ...
       MATCH(results.keywords) AGAINST('".DB::e($_POST['s'])."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS aaa,
       SUM( MATCH(tags.keywords) AGAINST('".DB::e($_POST['s'])."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ) AS bbb
  FROM table1
  JOIN table2 ... JOIN table3 ...
 WHERE (aaa > 0   here the alias doesn't work!
        OR bbb > 0   here the alias doesn't work! )
GROUP BY table1.id
ORDER BY aaa DESC,  but here the alias works!
         bbb DESC  but here the alias works!
```

If I remove the WHERE clause works perfectly... so what is wrong with my aliases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `HAVING` ([here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Having_%28SQL%29) and somewhat less helpfull: [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)); the `WHERE` clause gets evaluated before the aliases even exist ;)